# Прибавить значение к высоте ccs через jquery

Tags: jquery

У меня есть кнопка , нужно про каждом нажатии увеличить значение `height` блока на `100px`.
 Как это реализовать? Я могу изменить значение на определенное, но прибавлять не получается. Получается у меня есть блок, я прописываю ему при нажатии изменение стиля `css` на `100 px`, но дальше уже так не прокатит. Условие должно быть получается `height+100`, но синтаксис так не позволяет. Возможно создать новую переменную и прибавлять уже ее, что то типа `const`?

```
$('.body_site').css('height','200');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function more(id,h) {
    var $block = $("#" + id);

    $block.animate({
        'height' : '+=' + h + 'px'
    },'ease-out')
}
```

```css
#block{
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block"></div>
<button onclick="more('block',100);">more</button>
```